# What is the app.config solution for a Blazor project?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, web-config, blazor, blazor-server-side

What is the app.config / web.config solution for a Blazor app.
I am almost certain this is possible for the Blazor Server side project. But wondering more deeply how configuration will be handled for the Client side project.

Essentially, I need to know what kind of environment an app is running under (e.g. dev, test, production).

> What is the configuration story for Blazor?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's the same [Configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.2) as for **ASP.NET core**. You basically have an `appsettings.environment.json` file per environment and use the build in `IConfiguration` interface to [bind your settings to classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.2#bind-to-a-class). As such settings are stored in the `json` format:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "System": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information"
    }
  },
  "Serilog": {
    "LevelSwitches": { "$controlSwitch": "Debug" },
    "MinimumLevel": { "ControlledBy": "$controlSwitch" },
    "WriteTo": [
...
```

How many environments and how you call them, is up to you. 
Here is an example:

[image: ASP.NET core appsettings example]

At runtime the environment is deducted from the [OS environment variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable) `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT`'s value. For development purpose you can create profiles and set the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` wihtin your `launchSettings.json` like this:

```
"profiles": {
    "Development": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
}
```

After you deployed or started executing the `Blazor` app, the hosts `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` for both server-side and client-side applications will be used. Remember even if it's a client-side / SPA application, it is still hosted on a server. 
Also for client-side `Blazor`app, the `appsettings` won't be delivered to the client, you wouldn't want to expose your connectionstrings and other sensitive settings to your clients, right?

As a sidenote, if you host your `Blazor`app within IIS (as a reverse proxy) a **web.config** file will be created, for the purpose of instructing IIS how to start the app, what arguments to pass and some other things.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for this.

Comment: What is the recommended approach for providing the configuration payload in client-side applications?